# adding an PHP includes on HTML for Facebook Pixel Tracking

Tags: php, facebook, tracking

ok so the pages I created the includes for are all coded in HTML, Here is What I added between

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Trackers -->
<?php include '../../includes/facebook.php'; ?>
<?php include '../../includes/facebook-remarket.php'; ?>
```

This is facebook.php

```
 <?php
    <!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Page to shopping cart -->
    <script>(function() {
    var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
    if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
   _fbq.loaded = true;
    }
     })();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6025401909904', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6025401909904&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
?>
```

and this is the Facebook Remarking Pixel facebook-remarket.php

```
<?php
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '624907827655749']);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=624907827655749&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" /></noscript>
?>
```

The reason for adding an includes is becuase when adding the script the pixel shifts the header down ( goportcanaveral.com ), I am the SEO Analyst so I am currently just working with what I got until our new site is done, But I need to do some conversion tracking for facebook and I cant use onlick commands either since I already have it tagged for Analytics, Please help. They are not firing and facebook cant verify

Cheers,

Comment: here is a sample of a page that has the conversion tracking installed ( http://www.goportcanaveral.com/orlando-airport/americas-best-cocoa-beach/1-person-fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-package.html )

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the PHP Tags containing the javascript code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on how to use the site, including how to write the best possible answers.  In this case you could add some more information to explain why the OP should do what you suggest or how your solution solves the OP's problem.